# Android - как получить путь к файлу из Intent?

Tags: android, ui

Зарегистрировал своё приложение как плеер.

```
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:name=".MiniActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content"/>
            <data android:scheme="file"/>
            <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Как я понял, если открыть файл в проводнике, то моей программе в интенте передастся путь к файлу. А как его достать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri data = intent.getData();
```